# XSL-FO Extracting amount

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have this inside XML:

```
 <InvoiceList>
   <Invoice>
     <InvoiceAmount WithVATBool="false" VATAmount="96.2" VATPercentage="1" WithVAT="9716.19">9619.99</InvoiceAmount>
   </Invoice>
 </InvoiceList>
```

I want to extract this amount 9619.99 and the following inside FOP:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice/InvoiceAmount"/>
```

Is giving me this on my template 9619.99196.2

Any idea how to extract this because I tried with substring-after and then I get NaN.

Thanks!

Stylesheet in use:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery"
     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="brojac" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="timeBase" select="number(//TimeBase/@Val)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="filefolder" select="/data/imagepath" />
    <xsl:template match="/data">
     <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master 
                master-name="default-page" 
                page-height="279.4mm" 
                page-width="215.9mm" 
                margin-left="1cm" 
                margin-right="1cm" 
                margin-top="0.5cm" 
                margin-bottom="0.5cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="2cm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent="1cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-page">

            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data" mode="case_data"/>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:table
                        space-after="0.25cm"
                        table-layout="fixed"
                        width="100%"
                        color="black"
                        font-family="Arial"
                        font-size="10px"
                        text-align="center"
                        height="14px">

                        <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>

                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row height="14px">
                                <fo:table-cell                                      
                                font-family="Arial"
                                font-size="10px"
                                text-align="center"
                                color="black"
                                height="14px">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Član 1.
                                    </fo:block>
                                    <fo:block text-align="justify">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice/InvoiceAmount" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
       </fo:root>
      </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've removed all unecessary tables..

Comment: Your really need to show a complete stylesheet that demonstrates the problem, because the single line you have shown will not give the output you currently show. The problem is almost certainly somewhere else in your XSLT. Thank you.

Comment: Stylsheet is above..

Comment: I couldn't manage to recreate the problem with that. See http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy1T. I do notice you are doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="/data" mode="case_data"/>` but there is no node matcing `case_data` in your XSLT, so maybe the issue lies there?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `196.2` appearing elsewhere in your XML?  `//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice/InvoiceAmount` is selecting every `Task/InvoiceList/Invoice/InvoiceAmount` in your document, and you are seeing the concatenation of their values.

Without seeing more of your XML, it's hard to say much more, but you should reduce `//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice/InvoiceAmount` to the XPath that will select the `InvoiceAmount` that you want relative to the current `data` node.  It might be as simple as changing the XPath to `Task/InvoiceList/Invoice/InvoiceAmount` but, again, we can't tell without seeing more of your XML.

You have something similar with `<xsl:variable name="timeBase" select="number(//TimeBase/@Val)"/>`: you might get unexpected results if there is more than one `TimeBase` in the document.

Lastly, `exclude-result-prefixes="fo"` isn't going to do anything because the first thing that you generate is an element in the `fo` namespace.  It would be more useful to exclude the `s` and `exsl` prefixes.

Comment: I don't have 196.2 anywhere. 96.2 is under VATAmount and 1 is VATPercentage. This is the only InvoiceAmount that is in my XML.

Comment: The string value of an element is the concatenation of its text node descendents.  The attribute values are not part of the string value.  If they were somehow part of the string value, they would appear _before_ the value of the text node, since attributes come before descendants in document order.  Can you try changing the color on your innermost `fo:block` and seeing if all of the text changes color?